# Which gives a faster query? Which is cleaner? JOIN ON or WHERE

Tags: sql, database, join

When should I be using JOIN ON or WHERE in a scenario like the one below?

```
DECLARE
  @PhoneNumber int = 5551234

-- JOIN ON
SELECT *
FROM Persons
JOIN Employees ON Persons.DateOfBirth = Employees.DateOfBirth AND
Persons.PhoneNumber = Employees.PhoneNumber
WHERE Persons.PhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber

-- WHERE
SELECT *
FROM Persons
JOIN Employees ON Persons.DateOfBirth = Employees.DateofBirth
WHERE Persons.PhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber AND Employees.PhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber
```

I'm aware that the first query will have one PhoneNumber column, while the second will have two.  Will this significantly affect the speed of the query?

Comment: The two queries are not directly comparable. For the second, do you mean "WHERE Persons.PhoneNumber = Employee.PhoneNumber"... or possibly "SELECT * FROM Persons, Employee WHERE Persons.PhoneNumber = Employee.PhoneNumber"?

Comment: The queries are not equivalent - no point comparing their performance.

Comment: Also... break this habit now! "Persons" table and "Employee" table don't agree singular vs. plural. Standardize today! :)

Comment: lol Bob! I like all the table names to be plural.

Comment: Naming conventions are subjective, and irrelevant to the topic at hand.  All that matters is being consistent in the naming scheme.

Comment: I've cleaned up my poor example a bit.

Comment: You still need to fix your where clause as stated earlier for the queries to be equivalent.  You want "Employees.PhoneNumber = Persons.PhoneNumber" not "Employees.PhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber".  Although in theory it will work because you are using it to filter the table, it isn't properly equivalent to the join.

Comment: Could you explain why they are not equivalent?  Particularly if there is a difference between them other than the first having one PhoneNumber column, and the second having two PhoneNumber columns in the result.

Comment: Am I the only person who finds it scary that you are joining on phone number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Syntax errors aside, you're comparing ANSI-89 JOIN syntax (JOIN criteria in the WHERE clause) to ANSI-92 JOIN syntax (uses the JOIN keyword).

They perform identical to one another, but ANSI-89 lacks OUTER JOIN support so many databases have custom means of indicating OUTER joins:

```
database     ANSI-89 OUTER JOIN syntax
------------------------------------
Oracle       t1.column = t2.column(+)
SQL Server   t1.column =* t2.column
```

For sake of portability and readability--use ANSI-92 syntax.

Comment: Agree with ponies, old syntax vs newer syntax...accomplishes the same thing.  Ansi-92 is so much more readable

Comment: Part of the question was regarding cleanliness and Ansi-92 is by far cleaner IMO.  It separates conditions used for the join and conditions used for filtering what is returned.

Comment: And the SQL Server =* or *= syntax is currently broken and is not guaranteed to be right and it is deprecated.

Comment: are you sure? OP has `JOIN` in both queries.

Comment: @Marcus Adams: That's why I started my answer with "syntax errors..."  MySQL is the only DB I'm aware of that allows JOIN without an ON clause--it's a CROSS JOIN, which is what syntax you need to specify otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

For an inner join it makes no difference to the results whether predicates are put in the join condition or where clause.

I'd put stuff related to joining the tables in the join clause and stuff related to filtering in the where clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM Persons
JOIN Employee ON Persons.PhoneNumber = Employee.PhoneNumber
WHERE Persons.PhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

JOIN is the right choice for... joining tables logically connected with foreign keys. The reason is that you can set up different kind of joins (left, right, inner, outer).

WHERE is more a logical filtering of rows.

In your simple example, it makes no real difference between the two.